# Powershell Script for recursive deletion

Tags: powershell

I have started a new job and almost instantly been dropped in to do some Powershell, however I've only ever used Powershell in Exchange and very basic at that.

I will be doing more learning over the next few months but for now, I need a script that will go to an arbitrary folder, check every folder and subfolder recursively, deleting any files over 2 days old.

Can anyone assist a newbie on this please?'

```powershell
Function DelFiles($RootFolder,[ref]$blnDeleteErrmsgSent){
  $blnDeleteErrmsgSent  = $false
  $date                 = Get-Date
  $Folders              = Dir
  $FolderPath           = "path"
  $PSEmailServer        = "servername"

  # Delete Old Files
  Cd $RootFolder

  foreach($folder in $Folders){
    Cd $Folder.FullName
    $ToDelete = Dir -Attributes !readonly |Where {$_.lastwritetime -lt ((Get-Date).Adddays(-2))}
    foreach($File in $ToDelete){
      try{
        if($file.Attributes -notcontains "Directory"){
        Remove-Item -Path $File.FullName -Force -ErrorAction Stop}
      }catch{
        # Only Send e-mail alert if we haven't already done so i.e. only once
        if(!($blnDeleteErrmsgSent.value)){
          $errordescription=$_
          $errorline=$_.InvocationInfo.Line.ToString()

          # Capture Error Information
            # Notify IT that this script has encountered an error
            Send-MailMessage -From "ScanDeletion@****.co.uk" -To "IT@****.co.uk" -Subject "errored while deleting old scan files" -Body ("The error occured at " + [string]$date +"`n Error:"+ $errordescription +"`n Line:"+ $errorline)

            # Set Flag to True so we don't send multiple e-mail alerts for file deletion errors.
            $blnDeleteErrmsgSent.value = $true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# Call Archive Function (auto-recursive) to archive any xml files in Folder, and subfolders
DelFiles $FolderPath ([ref]$blnDeleteErrmsgSent)

Exit
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has it failed? [SU] isn't a code-writing service; we're here to _help_, but most of us won't _do it_ for you. Edit your question to include your code, explain where it fails, provide error messages and/or examples of desired output vs. actual output, and basically any information you can provide that will show us that you've tried to solve this on your own and have failed in non-obvious ways.

Comment: Apologies Jeff, I have very little PS knowledge, as far as writing them is concerned.
I have added the existing script to the post and this works but not recursively. I want it to do the recursive stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you weren't really far away, but here are the three things I would do different:

- Get all files with just one command by using the `-Recurse` switch of `Get-ChildItem`, instead of jumping from folder to folder just to get the files inside
- Instead of creating flags for the email, gather the information you want to send during your delete process, store them in an array, then send the email once
- Instead of checking if the file you want to delete is not a folder, use the `-File` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`

I would also use it as a script, not a `Function`, but that's your call:

```powershell
$RootFolder = "C:\install\su1587308"
$DeleteDate = (Get-Date).AddDays("-2")
$Fails      = @()

# Get all files below the rootfolder that are not ReadOnly:
Get-ChildItem $RootFolder -Recurse -Attributes !ReadOnly -File |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DeleteDate } | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
      Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    } Catch {
      # if it fails to the delete, the fullname of the file is stored in a variable
      $Fails += $_.FullName
    }
  }

# Only send an email if something failed:
if ($Fails) {
  $Body = "Could not delete the Following Files:<br>" +($Fails -join '<br>')
  $Splat = @{
    SmtpServer = "???"
    From       = "ScanDeletion@****.co.uk"
    To         = "IT@****.co.uk"
    Subject    = "errored while deleting old scan files"
    Body       = $Body
    BodyAsHtml = $true
  }

  Send-MailMessage @Splat
}
```

Comment: could i talk you into replacing those nasty, icky backticks with a splat? not only would it be easier to read ... it would help tech folks to avoid using backticks. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sure. i like those backticks though. I only need to use them on `send-mailmessage` that's why i always use them

Comment: Thanks Simon. I will give that a go. Thank you so much

Comment: @SimonS - thank you! backticks are so very easy to leave behind when editing ... and so very hard to see in most editors. [*grin*]